# custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i need to create a screen which is a replication of the default iphone stock application without the scrolling on the bottom table , what would u think is the best way to replicate the look and feel of the screen ? 
i've created a uiview and added two uitableview setting the delegate and datasource to the same view for both of them and styled them with a grouped styling , now that comes close but i'm having problem reproducing the bottom table which has a html like look&feel , how can i create a table cell like that ? and stop the lower table from scrolling ? 
thanks .

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "iphone stock application"?

Comment: the default application that ships with the iphone called stocks

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to do something similar to the default "Stocks" App.  If I were trying to recreate that App, I would probably only use one UITableView, for the upper section that displays the list of stock prices.  The bottom section does not display a list so you would probably be better off using a basic UIView or one of it's subclasses.  In the Stocks App specifically, Apple seems to be using a UIScrollView with paging enabled, which allows you to swipe back and forth between the different screens.  However, if you are trying to display something with "html like look&feel" you might want to try a UIWebView instead.

Comment: thanks i didn't think about that option in regards to the uiwebview